# how to remove '?' sign in the end of file read in java

Tags: java, file-handling, fileinputstream

i m learning file input output and i m having a problem in it.***a.txt*** have some text and when it read and print the world there is'?'mark at the end.. how to remove it.

```
import java.io.*;
    class fRead{

            public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
            {

                FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("a.txt");
                int i=0;
                while(i!=-1){
                    i=fin.read();
                    System.out.print((char)i);
                }

                fin.close();
            }

    }
```

the result in CMD:-
  G:\file>javac fRead.java
 G:\file>java fRead
VINAYAK COMPUTER ACADEMY?

the***'?'*** in the end is not in the end of file.

Comment: Its an issue with the way you wrote your while loop. You are checking break condition before assigning value to "i", It will loop for -1 also and print the same. Assign value to i first and then check "i != -1"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem happens because you print `-1` that you get from the `read()` after converting it to `char`, even though the loop should stop without printing anything when `-1` is returned.

You can fix it by combining the assignment with the check for negative one:

```
while ((i = fin.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)i);
}
```